# What's wrong with this code to assign a token in the email_token_expiry varchar field?

Tags: python, django

```
def register(request):
    flag = True
    possible = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    token = ''
    length = 10
    i = 0

    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

    user = UsersModelForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userf = UsersModelForm(request.POST)
        username = userf.data['username']
        password = userf.data['password']
        passwordrepeat = userf.data['passwordrepeat']
        email = userf.data['email']

        if password != passwordrepeat:
            flag = False
            passVariable = {'user':user, 'flag': False}
            return render_to_response('register.html', passVariable, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        elif password == passwordrepeat:
            while i<10:
                temp = random.choice(possible)
                token = token + temp
                i=i+1

            userf.email_token = token
            userf.email_token_expiry = current_datetime + timedelta(1)
            userf.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('register.html', {"user": user, 'flag': True}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

From the MySQL promt:

`select * from blog_users;` I got empty values in `email_token field`, why? `print token` displays the correct token, but it's not inserting the token string into `email_token field`.

**models.py**:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    passwordrepeat = models.CharField('Repeat Password', max_length=300)
    password_token = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='0')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email_token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_token_expiry = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_action = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

class UsersModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'passwordrepeat', 'email')
        widgets = {
            'password' : PasswordInput(),
            'passwordrepeat' : PasswordInput(),
        }
```

Comment: Which class has email_token property?

Comment: @disorder, i updated the original post, see that again to understand.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, i updated the original post, see that again to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to update the model, not the form.

```
newuser = userf.save(commit=False)
newuser.email_token = token
newuser.email_token_expiry = current_datetime + timedelta(1)
newuser.save()
```

Comment: Why `commit=False`? `newuser = userf.save(commit=False)` , but `userf.save()` saved the value of `email_token_expiry`, then what was the problem saving `email_token` value? And this method `commit=False` looks unusual, is there any other(common) way to do it?

Comment: You need `commit=False` if e.g. the fields you're updating after are `null=False`.

Comment: Also, the token generation could be simplified into this: `''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for x in range(10))`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, why are you using `save()` function twice? It's not for updating in this case, it's adding/inserting a new row.

Comment: @guru Those `save`'s are different. You don't have a model object in the first place, but a form object. First, you need to use `save` on the form to get a model object, then modify the model object and then save it.